# System.Windows.Data Error: 17: RowNotInTableException

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a DataTable to a WPF DataGrid at runtime. The code looks as follows:

```
DataTable c_tblData;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    c_tblData = new DataTable("tblData");
    c_tblData.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    c_tblData.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
    c_tblData.Columns.Add("OK", typeof(bool));
    dgrData.ItemsSource = c_tblData.DefaultView;
 }
```

I do not have other code behind. The XAML is very simple, too:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_DataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_DataGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dgrData" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Inserting and updating new rows is no problem. Bit when I try to abort adding a new row by pressing the ESC key twice, I get the following error (in the immediate window only):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'OK' value (type 'Boolean') from '' (type 'DataRowView'). BindingExpression:Path=OK; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=26031876); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1') RowNotInTableException:'System.Data.RowNotInTableException: Diese Zeile wurde aus einer Tabelle entfernt und enthält keine Daten. BeginEdit() ermöglicht das Erstellen von neuen Daten in dieser Zeile.
```

Why do I get this error and how can I get rid of it? I did an extensive search on the topic but did'nt came to a conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely just ignore this exception. It's harmless and already handled for you.

The exception is thrown when you try to perform an operation on a `DataRow` that is not in a `DataTable` but you can't really control how and when the `DataGrid` control add or removes rows to the `DataTable` unless you override the behaviour of the `ESC` keypress somehow:

```
private void dgrData_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Escape;
}
```

But there is no need to this really.

Comment: Overriding the behaviour as in your suggestions actually prevents the error from popping up. But: I'm no longer able to abort neither the cell editing nor the row adding. Thus, it's no solution... Of course I can ignore the error, but I find it annoying and would really like to get rid of it.

Comment: Thatäs what I mean. *Don't* bother about this exception because it is harmless and doesn't have anything to do with your code. You should focus on more important things :)